# Cannot delete indices with curator elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk, elasticsearch-curator

I am trying to deleate all the logs that are were stored 14 days ago or before in elasticsearch. I have installed curator , and created the config file and the action file, in this way:

[curator.yml configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWl9T.png)

My elasticsearch is running in localhost:8080 ,and kibana in localhost:80

[delete_indices action file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Besju.png)

With both configurations file, I execute the currator with the config files and i obtain this:

[command execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIToH.png)

You can see in the following image, my index name in kibana:

[filebeat index in kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0QCW.png)

I've already tried many things, however I didn't manage to make it work, it allways says there is no index with this name. Do someone know where could be the issue?

Edit 1:
With your help, I managed to get the exact index name, however I still have the same problem:

[modified delete_indices.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6ytb.png)

That's what i get when i enter GET _cat/indices:

[my indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8vs0.png)

Comment: What you see in the kibana screenshot is the name of the kibana index pattern, not the indices itself. Open the  dev tools and execute `GET _cat/indicies` in order to see the current present indicies.

Comment: okay, so the result I get is the following: 

green  open .kibana_task_manager_1           Hmiisy2XR9eEKOEdJOV6MQ 1 0      2 1  38.5kb  38.5kb

green  open .apm-agent-configuration         bL2vmSFURY6yGvhBcnfrpw 1 0      0 0    283b    283b

green  open .kibana_1                        IjoATFSQSA2bmIpOJ5mzCw 1 0   1063 6 700.2kb 700.2kb

yellow open filebeat-7.5.1-2020.01.22-000001 IsBVn9I-SMCp7rCMz-I5ow 1 1 303387 0 185.6mb 185.6mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that curator will not act on any index associated with an ILM policy without setting allow_ilm_indices to to true.

The solution was:

[image: custom delete_indices file]

[image: allow_ilm_indices]

More information: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.8/option_allow_ilm.html